# Webpack dynamically loading a node_module at runtime in browser

Tags: webpack, node-modules, dynamic-loading

**Use case:**

- DB contains list of widgets names each user can see
- Each widget is a node_module
- We need to load the widget node module dynamically in UI

## Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { StaticRouter,Route, Switch, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
const AsyncComponent = (moduleName) => {
  return require('../node_modules/' + moduleName) //This line is not working if the moduleName is mentioned at runtime, if it is statically mentioned then it works fine.
  //or something like
  return import('../node_modules/' + moduleName)

}
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component{
  state = {
    widgets : [],
    appIsMounted: false
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/widgets', (response) => { //DB contains list of widgets names for the specific user and there will be node_module for each widget or functionality.
      this.setState({
        widgets: response.data //list of functionalities or widgets to show in the UI
      })
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <StaticRouter>
          <div>
 **strong text**               {
                    this.state.widgets && this.state.widgets.map(module => {
                        return <nav>
                            <NavLink to={`/${module}`} exact activeClassName="active">{module.module}</NavLink>
                            </nav>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <div>
              <Switch>
              {
                this.state.widgets && this.state.widgets.map(module => {
                  return <Route path={`/${module}`} exact component={AsyncComponent.bind(this, module)} />
                })
              }
            </Switch>
            </div>
            </StaticRouter>
        )
  }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- You dont need to prefix the path of your module name with `../node_modules`. All modules are automatically resolved unless the resolve config is overridden explicitly.
- I faced the same issue once too if I'm understanding it right. Can you please try once by inlining the AsyncComponent function inside your Route JSX. Also, it should be like this

```js
const asyncComponent = bundle => (location, cb) => {
 bundle().then(component => {
  cb(null, component.default ? component.default : component);
 });
};

asyncComponent(() =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "CategoryLanding" */ 'pages/CategoryLandingPage/CategoryLandingPage.js')
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
-   I have tried same way that you mentioned asyncComponent in inline and it works because you are passing file name statically.

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "CategoryLanding" */ 'pages/CategoryLandingPage/CategoryLandingPage.js') //staticaly mentioned and it works as webpack knows at compile time`
`import(/* webpackChunkName: "CategoryLanding" */ '<Should be passed dynamically>') //It doesn't know about this chunk at compile time
</Code>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in babelLoader or in your Webpack config.

Exclude only node modules:

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

Exclude node modules and some other libraries

For eg: i will use salesforce-ux library as my external library

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@salesforce-ux)\/).*/
```